# Where in London is 12 Grimmauld Place?

Tags: harry-potter, real-location, grimmauld-place

As of *Order of the Phoenix* (summer of 1995), 12 Grimmauld Place is a townhouse in a cul-du-sac located in a run-down neighborhood of London.

The fashionableness of neighborhoods changes quite frequently in cities, but presumably, Grimmauld Place was a fashionable neighborhood when the Black family initially occupied it (or maybe not...).

I don't know much about London myself, but **are there enough clues in the story to get an approximate neighborhood for 12 Grimmauld Place?**

- Do we know how far back into the Black family 12 Grimmauld Place goes (Phineas Nigellus's portrait and the mounted house-elves might be a clue)?
- the age of the neighborhood (architecture, layout of rooms, number of storeys, density of houses) might be a clue
- distance from King's Cross might be a clue

Comment: Right next to number 11 Grimmauld Place. Duh.

Comment: In real life it's at [23-29 Claremont Square, Islington](http://www.freetoursbyfoot.com/harry-potters-london-part-3-north/). Very expensive indeed.

Comment: Why was number 11 Grimmauld Place afraid of number 12 Grimmauld Place? ...Because number 12 Grimmauld Place number 13 Grimmauld Place number 14 Grimmauld Place!

Comment: @Irregardless Ah, that classic expression of humor!  I show my appreciation of your humor by vibrating my larynx and opening my mouth, emitting a chuckling sound for all the world to hear!

Comment: https://legacy.hp-lexicon.org/essays/essay-in-search-of-grimmauld-place.html

Comment: @Valorum shouldn't be. It should be next to number 10 and number 14.

Comment: @Po-ta-toe - Street numbers only alternate where there are opposing houses. Most London terraced houses are numbered *sequentially* in my experience.

Comment: @Valorum bloody Londoners

Comment: "23-29 Claremont Square, Islington". Quite close to King's Cross then...

Comment: @Po-ta-toe: The book clearly states the numbering is sequential, as Valorum said: *They were standing outside number eleven; he looked to the left and saw number ten; to the right, however, was number thirteen. (…) a battered door emerged out of nowhere between numbers eleven and thirteen, followed swiftly by dirty walls and grimy windows.*

Comment: @chirlu I said shouldn't. Not wasn't

Comment: @ibid you basically answered the question

Comment: @Irregardless - I didn't have the patience to compress it into something that I felt would fit this site's format.

Comment: @ibid Yeah...it appears neither did Witherwings...

Comment: I suppose that the real house is occupied by bearded hipsters now :)

Comment: Nice try Voldemort.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**There is no definite location according to canon sources, however some educated guesses have been made on possible locations.**

First and foremost, there seems to be some inaccurate information out there saying that it was in Islington. The scenes in the film *were* filmed in Islington, and, from available evidence, Islington *could* be where Grimmauld Place is located in-universe, however there doesn't appear to be anything in canon sources that definitely say Islington is the place. The filming location for the movie was done at "Claremont Square, Islington, London N1" <sup>[1](http://hpsupporters.com/hp-attractions/filming-locations/london.html)</sup>  This may be where the confusion in some sources comes from.

There does not appear to be a real world location for 12 Grimmauld Place. However, with some detective work, some approximations can be made.

> Grimmauld Place was therefore probably about three quarters of a mile
> from King’s Cross, somewhere to the north of it, and closer to either
> Camden Town or Caledonian Road station than it is to King’s Cross.
> Consequently, the Ministry of Magic is probably near Leicester Square
> or Charing Cross stations, close to both the Leaky Cauldron and to the
> Muggle government ministries.<sup>[2](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/2006/01/16/in-search-of-grimmauld-place/)</sup>

Please see the quoted portions below for more detail on how this was ascertained.

This excellent detective work, by Ravenclaw Rambler, uses the books to determine possible locations for Grimmauld place.

> Number twelve, Grimmauld Place is the location of much of the action
> in Chapters 4 to 10 of Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix. It
> is Sirius Black’s ancestral home, and the headquarters of the Order of
> the Phoenix. This essay discusses its possible location, and also that
> of the Ministry of Magic.
>
> It has been suggested that Grimmauld Place is in the Tufnell Park area
> of north London, with which JKR was familiar. However, this is
> two-and-a-half miles from King’s Cross railway station, and a passage
> at the beginning of OP10 makes it clear that King’s Cross is only a
> twenty-minute walk away—for a large group encumbered by a lot of heavy
> luggage. This puts Grimmauld Place about a mile, or a bit less, from
> King’s Cross. Grimmauld Place must therefore lie on a circle a little
> less than a mile in radius, with King’s Cross at its centre.
>
> What else do we know? Well, in OP7 we have a description of Harry and
> Mr. Weasley’s journey by Underground to the Ministry of Magic. There
> are several very interesting points about this journey. Firstly, they
> walk along several streets to a “miserable little underground
> station.” King’s Cross is served by the Underground as well as the
> main line station: indeed, with eight platforms, it is one of the
> biggest on the Underground network. Clearly King’s Cross does not
> answer the description of the station used by Harry and Mr. Weasley.
> It is presumably more convenient to use this small station, rather
> than King’s Cross, for the journey to the Ministry of Magic. Any
> location identified for Grimmauld Place must be consistent with a
> plausible reason for not taking the Underground from this station to
> go to King’s Cross to catch the Hogwarts Express on September 1st.
>
> Secondly, it is stated several times that the journey on the
> Underground takes Harry and Mr. Weasley to the very heart of
> London—therefore the station they go to is significantly more central
> than the station they started at. Moreover, at one point Mr. Weasley
> tells Harry that there are “four more stops”—indicating that they
> travel at least four stops, and probably more.
>
> Finally, they arrive at a station which they leave by escalator. This
> is significant because in general only the deep-level tube lines built
> after 1890 have escalators. The Circle Line and the three other lines
> it shares tracks with date from mid-Victorian times, and were
> originally worked by steam trains, which of course needed ventilation
> to allow the steam to escape. They are much closer to the surface and
> their platforms are reached by ordinary stairs.
>
> So, we are looking for somewhere rather insalubrious, a little less
> than one mile from King’s Cross, whose nearest tube station is on a
> deep level tube line, and from which a journey of four stops or more
> on the Underground will take you to a station in central London. Note
> that the tube station itself may be more or less than twenty minutes’
> walk from King’s Cross.
>
> There are no less than fifteen stations on the London Underground
> within a mile of King’s Cross: in alphabetical order they are Angel,
> Caledonian Road, Camden Town, Chancery Lane, Euston, Euston Square,
> Farringdon, Goodge Street, Great Portland Street, Highbury &
> Islington, Holborn, Mornington Crescent, Russell Square, Tottenham
> Court Road, and Warren Street. Let us see if we can narrow it down a
> bit.
>
> King’s Cross is on the northern edge of central London—see map at
> http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=51.530640,-0.123596&spn=0.035355,0.070694&hl=en.
>
> A diagrammatic map of the underground network can be found at
> https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/large-print-tube-map.pdf.
>
> Harry and Mr. Weasley travel “towards central London,” so we can
> assume that they start from a station that is less central than their
> destination. Moreover, if they started too near the centre, a journey
> of four or more stops would take them out of the central area.
>
> Let us perform an orbit of King’s Cross, starting in the east, and
> working round clockwise.
>
> Due east of King’s Cross, a bit less than a mile away in Islington, is
> Angel Station, on the Northern Line. I think we can eliminate this
> one, as if you travel four stops north or south you will be heading
> away from the centre of London. Interestingly, on Pentonville Road,
> leading uphill from King’s Cross to the Angel, there is a small park
> named after Joseph Grimaldi (1779 – 1837) the father of modern circus
> clowning, who was buried in this former churchyard
> http://www.its-behind-you.com/grimaldi.html. It would be nice to think
> of Grimaldi Park as being Grimmauld Place, but if it were, surely
> Harry and Mr Weasley would have used nearby King’s Cross station in
> OP7, not a “miserable little” one further away (and uphill). [fn1]
>
> South-east of King’s Cross is Farringdon, on the Circle Line, and
> nearby is Chancery Lane, on the Central Line. These are both much too
> central: Chancery Lane in particular is in the centre of “Lawyers
> London” (Chancery is one of the divisions of the High Court). This
> seems to be an unlikely area to find Grimmauld Place. I have already
> explained why the Circle Line’s absence of escalators at its stations
> makes that line unlikely, whilst if you travel four or more stops away
> from Chancery Lane you are heading away from the centre of London, and
> also rapidly run out of stations with escalators—many Central Line
> stations still use lifts.
>
> To the south of King’s Cross we have Holborn and Tottenham Court Road.
> Again, these are large stations, and are very central, so that
> travelling four or more stops from either of these would take you away
> from the centre of London.
>
> Aldwych is an interesting possibility—definitely run down in the mid
> 1990s, and with a peak-hour-only service it could not have been used
> to go to King’s Cross for 11am. Against it though, we find that it was
> extremely central, it was one end of a shuttle service to Holborn, so
> they would have to change there (people who count stops on the first
> leg of a tube journey on which they have to change trains, only count
> to the interchange station) and it closed in May 1994. This would put
> the dates in the canon out by at least two years since the date of
> Nearly Headless Nick’s Deathday in CS8 gives the events in the early
> part ofOrder of the Phoenix as having taken place in August 1995.
>
> A little closer to King’s Cross lies Bloomsbury, served by Russell
> Square station, with Goodge Street a little further west. These are
> both quite small stations, near the edge of the central area, and
> travelling four stops south would take you to Piccadilly Circus or
> Embankment respectively, which are both very central. Goodge Street is
> of particular interest because the journey from Goodge Street to
> King’s Cross would involve a change of trains, so it may be easier to
> walk rather than take the underground.
>
> We now come to a collection of stations, on various lines, strung out
> close together along the Euston Road to the south west of King’s
> Cross. Great Portland Street and Euston Square are on the Circle Line,
> and the same considerations as at Farringdon would seem to rule them
> out. Euston is a big Underground station—it serves a main line station
> bigger than King’s Cross. Warren Street is a possibility—it is four
> stops from Charing Cross, the official centre of London, from which
> distances are measured, and at the end of Whitehall, where most
> Government Ministries are located—perhaps including the Ministry of
> Magic. However, Warren Street is on a direct line to King’s Cross—if
> Grimmauld Place was near Warren Street, why did the party not use it
> to travel to King’s Cross on September 1st?
>
> West of King’s Cross lies Mornington Crescent, famous from the BBC
> radio comedy show I’m Sorry I Haven’t a Clue—the game Mornington
> Crescent has only one rule, which is that the players take turns to
> name a Tube station, and the first one to say “Mornington Crescent” is
> the winner! The station is small, not on a direct line to King’s
> Cross, and four stops would take you to Tottenham Court Road, five to
> Leicester Square and six to Charing Cross, all of which are very
> central. This would be a most promising candidate except for the
> unfortunate circumstance that it was mothballed from 1992 to 1998,
> neatly bracketing the events in the early part of Order of the
> Phoenix, for which the canonical date is 1995, as I have already
> discussed.
>
> About twenty minutes walk north of King’s Cross lies York Way station.
> This is definitely very run down, and would fit the bill almost
> perfectly except for the fact that it closed in 1932. If Harry and Mr
> Weasley used this station, we have to resolve a very large number of
> anomalies: Harry would have had to be born no later than 1917.  Frank
> Bryce could have been injured in the Crimean War (or maybe the
> American Civil War), but the Ford Anglia appearing in Chamber of
> Secrets would have had to be fitted with a “flux capacitor” like the
> DeLorean in Back to the Future (or perhaps a Time-Turner) as no Ford
> was badged as an Anglia until 1940! I think we’d better carry on
> looking!
>
> There remain Camden Town, to the north west of King’s Cross,
> Caledonian Road, to the north (just off the attached map), and
> Highbury & Islington to the northeast. As these are all rather further
> than a mile from King’s Cross, Grimmauld Place would have to be some
> distance to the south of them to be only a twenty-minute walk from
> King’s Cross. This actually supports them as possibilities, as it
> would explain why they were not used for the journey to King’s Cross.
> (Another possible explanation is that Camden Town is “exit only” on
> Sunday mornings to reduce the crowds visiting Camden Market, so it
> could not have been used to travel to King’s Cross to catch the
> Hogwarts Express at 11am on the day before term started—Hogwarts terms
> always seem to start on Mondays. <sup>A</sup> ) At the canonical date of 1995
> the area had some seedy parts, although it has been largely
> “gentrified” in the subsequent ten years, and a large area was swept
> away for the construction of the new railway line connecting St.
> Pancras station to the Channel Tunnel. To see what it used to be like,
> watch the 1950s Ealing comedy The Ladykillers, much of which was
> filmed on location in this area.
>
> Five stops from Highbury & Islington takes you to Green Park station:
> on the other side of the eponymous park lies Whitehall, the Muggle
> seat of government. Could this also be where the Ministry of Magic is
> to be found? It’s possible, although the walk to the Ministry of Magic
> is said to be through the streets rather than a park.
>
> More promisingly, five stops from either Caledonian Road (on the
> Piccadilly Line) or Camden Town (on the Northern Line), takes you to
> the intersection of those two lines at Leicester Square station, which
> is on the Charing Cross Road, where the Leaky Cauldron is to be found
> (see Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone). Although distance is
> no object to wizards who can Apparate, it would make some kind of
> sense for the wizards’ pub to be near the Ministry of Magic. One more
> stop down the Northern Line takes you to Charing Cross itself, at the
> northern end of Whitehall.
>
> Grimmauld Place was therefore probably about three quarters of a mile
> from King’s Cross, somewhere to the north of it, and closer to either
> Camden Town or Caledonian Road station than it is to King’s Cross.
> Consequently, the Ministry of Magic is probably near Leicester Square
> or Charing Cross stations, close to both the Leaky Cauldron and to the
> Muggle government ministries.
> <sup>[HP Lexicon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/2006/01/16/in-search-of-grimmauld-place/)</sup>

A - An alternative explanation as to why the day after the arrival at Hogwarts (2nd September) always seems to be a Monday is that Hogwarts may choose to operate a normal Monday timetable on the first day of term, regardless of what day of the week it actually is — just as my local railway company operates a Sunday service on Good Friday, and a church may have its usual Sunday services on festivals like Christmas and Ascension Day. Similar tinkering with the school calendar would help to explain a lot of date anomalies in the books, such as why there were lessons on Valentines Day 1993 (which was a Sunday), or even how there could be two Mondays in a row.<sup>[2](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/2006/01/16/in-search-of-grimmauld-place/)</sup>

From the available evidence, it would seem that Grimmauld Place would fall somewhere on this map:
[image: Grimmauld Possibilities]

Final Note : The HP Wikia is a really bad source of information, I have learned this the hard way while trying to back up my memory of events.

Answer (score 2):

Canonically... **We Don't Know<sup><sup>TM</sup></sup>**.

Pottermore lists the location of [Number Twelve, Grimmauld Place](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/number-twelve-grimmauld-place) as **London** only.

There is no specific writing on the location, like there is for [Number Four, Privet Drive](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/number-four-privet-drive) as an example. However, Pottermore is the source for canon information for the Wizarding World, so if any information in canon was presented, it would have been listed.

Update:

The Diagon Alley attraction at Universal Studios (Orlando, FL) displays placard on the Gimmauld Place building as London Borough of Islington. However I suspect as the other answer here states that this because of the filming location.  I also don't lend any real canon level to an amusement park but I still though it was neat...

[image]

Comment: Or the Pottermore team just made a mistake. We're talking about the team [who mixed mixed up McGonagall with Snape](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mSJPUgApqSM/VlMy2E1KT5I/AAAAAAAAE5M/ICuO77H8iAY/s2400/errori%2BPottermore.png). Them not knowing something is hardly conclusive.

Comment: You're going to make a lot of $ on that trademark :)

Comment: Hope you don't mind me fixing up that trademark a little.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently it is somewhere in Islington. The London Borough of Islington is just next to Camden Borough which is where Kings Cross is located. It was chosen as a filming location in accordance with a conversation David Yates had had with Jo.